# Matching a dependency using `subst` function in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a rule for the target

```
data/processed/21.12.2021/experiment6/written_piv21122021.005.exp6.mp4
```

in my makefile such that it has a dependency

```
data/raw/21.12.2021/experiment6/piv21122021.005.exp6.mov
```

Using `subst` functions, I'm trying to create the dependency by pattern matching as

```
%/written_*.mp4: \
$(subst processed,raw, $$*)/*.mov \
    <do something>
```

However, the above rule can't find the *.mov dependency. i have tried many versions of     `$(subst processed,raw, $$*)/*.mov` to match the dependency but didn't work.

How to do this? What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can't do this:

```
%/written_*.mp4:
```

You can't combine a pattern `%` with a wildcard `*`.  You have to realize that make works in two very discrete steps: first, all the makefiles are parsed and an internal representation of all the targets and prerequisites are constructed into a graph.  Then, make walks that graph figuring out what needs to be built and how to build it, and running recipes.

Make variables, functions, and wildcards in targets and prerequisites are expanded when makefiles are parsed (in the first step).  Automatic variables like `$*` are not set until a recipe is invoked (the second step), and patterns like `%` are not matched/expanded until make tries to decide how to build something (again in the second step).

So, a rule like:

```
%/written_*.mp4: $(subst processed,raw, $$*)/*.mov
```

can't work because the wildcard will expand to files matching the literal filename `%/written_*.mp4` which clearly has no matches since you won't have a directory named `%`.  In any event you can't use wildcards in *targets* because when make is parsing the makefile those targets won't exist (since that's what you want make to build) so the wildcards won't match anything.  Also, `$$*` is the literal string `$*` and there is no `processed` string in that so the `subst` function will do nothing.  And, even if `/*.mov` did match something it would put ALL the files matching that wildcard as prerequisites of *every* target so they'd all get rebuilt whenever any one changed.

And finally, you definitely should not use a backslash after your prerequisites: this just turns your recipe into prerequisites.

Your problem is very difficult to solve because your target and prerequisite differ in multiple distinct places and make doesn't support multiple `%` matching.  You can get most of the way there with this:

```
data/processed/%.mp4: data/raw/%.mov
        <do something>
```

However this is not quite right because the `%` in the target is `written_...` while in the prerequisite it's just `...` and this is not possible to represent in make.

If you can rework the filenames so that instead of `written_piv21122021.005.exp6.mp4` you can use `piv21122021.005.exp6.written.mp4` (or even better you don't need the `written_` prefix at all) then you can easily do this.  If not you'll need to get very fancy to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an imperfect kludge.

Delegate the work to another makefile I'll call `adjunct.mk`. In the main makefile:

```
data/processed/%.mp4:
    @$(MAKE) -f adjunct.mk $@
```

And in `adjunct.mk` this ugly transformation:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(MAKECMDGOALS): $$(patsubst data/processed/%,data/raw/%,$$(subst written_,,$$(patsubst %.mp4,%.mov,$$@)))
    ...do whatever with $< and $@...
```

This incurs the usual cost of recursive Make: it blinds the higher-level Make to the dependency relations being tracked by the lower one. So if your Make must build that `mov` file, or you try to build the `mp4` when the `mov` does not exist, then this solution will require some more careful pipefitting before it will work correctly.